# error An unexpected error occurred: "EACCES: permission denied in github actions

Tags: javascript, typescript, yarnpkg

Today when I run the yarn command in [github actions](https://github.com/jiangxiaoqiang/react-admin/actions), shows error like this:

```
Run rm -rf node-modules
yarn install v1.22.17
[1/5] Validating package.json...
[2/5] Resolving packages...
[3/5] Fetching packages...
error An unexpected error occurred: "EACCES: permission denied, unlink '/home/runner/work/react-admin/react-admin/node_modules/.yarn-integrity'".
info If you think this is a bug, please open a bug report with the information provided in "/home/runner/work/react-admin/react-admin/yarn-error.log".
info Visit https://yarnpkg.com/en/docs/cli/install for documentation about this command.
Error: Process completed with exit code 1.
```

I have already tried to delete the `node_modules` folder, by the way, the github actions virtual machine is new and did not contains the `node_modules` folder originally. what should I do to fix this problem? this is my github workflow define:

```
name: management-system-pro-umi

on:
  push:
    branches: [ umi ]

jobs:
  build:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:
      - uses: actions/checkout@v2
      - uses: actions/setup-node@v2
        with:
          node-version: 14
      - name: Install yarn
        uses: borales/actions-yarn@v2.1.0
        with: 
         cmd: install
      - name: Build React App
        run: | 
          rm -rf node_modules
          yarn
          umi build

      - name: Build image push to aliyun
        uses: docker/build-push-action@v1
        with:
          registry: ${{ secrets.ALI_DOCKER_HUB_REGISTRY }}
          username: ${{ secrets.ALIYUN_DOCKER_REPO_USER_NAME }}
          password: ${{ secrets.ALIYUN_DOCKER_REPO_USER_PASSWORD }}
          tags: ${{ github.sha }}
          repository: reddwarf-pro/react-admin-new
          path: '.'
    
       # https://github.com/steebchen/kubectl
      - name: deploy to cluster
        uses: steebchen/kubectl@v2.0.0
        with: # defaults to latest kubectl binary version
          config: ${{ secrets.KUBE_CONFIG_DATA }}
          command: set image --record deployment/react-admin-new react-admin=registry.cn-hangzhou.aliyuncs.com/reddwarf-pro/react-admin-new:${{ github.sha }} -n reddwarf-pro

      - name: verify deployment
        uses: steebchen/kubectl@v2.0.0
        with:
          config: ${{ secrets.KUBE_CONFIG_DATA }}
          version: v1.21.0 # specify kubectl binary version explicitly
          command: rollout status deployment/react-admin-new -n reddwarf-pro
```

I have read some other question, the all facing the problem in local machine. In the github actions virtual machine, when run into the yarn command, the error occured.

Comment: interesting that `rm -rf node-modules` doesn't result in an error, since the folder is `node_modules`

Comment: I changed the folder name still have a permission problem, I did not figure out why this have a permission problem, all the steps did not use any root or other user, why have a permission problem? @Bravo

Comment: on my local mac book pro it works fine. @Bravo

Answer (score 0):

I read the [official docs](https://github.com/Borales/actions-yarn) and found this:

> Please keep in mind that this Action was originally written for GitHub
> Actions beta (when Docker was the only way of doing things). Consider
> using actions/setup-node to work with Yarn. This repository will be
> mostly supporting the existing flows.

so I changed to use actions/setup-node repo, and do it like this:

```
jobs:
  build:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:
      - uses: actions/checkout@v2
      - uses: actions/setup-node@v2
        with:
          node-version: 16
      - run: npm install yarn -g
      - name: Build React App
        run: | 
          yarn
          yarn global add umi
          umi build
```

fixed it.